# Can't read the text from ComboBox

Tags: c#, windows, forms, combobox

I have a form (Form1) and a class (classx). I have a problem with reading the text from the comboBox2 from Form1 to classx. When I click any text from the comboBox2 while debugging, it shows me "*o:oo:oo*", like I didn't click anything from the comboBox2. I know the problem consist in the if() row, because if I leave it like: **form1.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()**, or **form1.comboBox2.SelectedText.ToString()**, or **form1.comboBox.Text**, or any other option (which I looked it up here in stackoverflow.com and in Google), it still shows me 0:00:00. **But**, if I write it like: if(**"Rome"**==Places[i]), it calculates the value for Rome, showing *01:07:30*.How to read the text from the combobox, which would work in my code?

Here is my class:

```
public class classx
{        
    public string[] Places = new string[] { "Berlin", "Paris", "London", "Rome", "Tirana", "Istanbul" };
    public int[] Kilometers = new int[] { 50, 30, 70, 110, 40, 90 };
    public TimeSpan Times()
    {
        double length = 0; double hour = 0, minute = 0, seconds = 0; int hour1 = 0, minute1 = 0, second1 = 0;
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            //this is the row which doesn't work
            if (form1.comboBox2.SelectedText.ToString() == Places[i])
            {
                length = Kilometers[i];
            }
        }
        hour = (length / 80);
        hour1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(hour));
        minute = (hour - Math.Truncate(hour)) * 60;
        minute1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(minute));
        second = (minute - Math.Truncate(minute)) * 60;
        second1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(second));
        TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(hour), Convert.ToInt32(minute1), Convert.ToInt32(second1));
        TimeSpan TimeLength = new TimeSpan(hour1, minute1, second1);
        return TimeLength;
    }
}
```

And here is my Form1

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        classx duration = new classx();

        MessageBox.Show("From " + comboBox1.Text + " to " + comboBox2.Text + " it takes around " + duration.Times());
    }
}
```

There are no errors shown. Any idea how to get the text from the comboBox2?

Edit: For future visitiors who have the samea question, this answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34794775/5749161

Comment: SelectedText returns the highlighted portion of the current text.  You probably want `comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Comment: if I don't write form1.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString(), an error appears because combobox2 wouldn't exist in the current context. If I write form1.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString(), my result shows 0:00:00

Comment: Doesn't look like you are referencing the existing form.  ClassX shouldn't know anything about your form.  Pass a reference of the data to your Times function with the proper parameters coming from your form.

Comment: Beside Form1 form1=new Form1() and calling it by form1, I don't know any other reference. Could you show me an edited code of mine, as I don't know how to do that :/

Comment: You need to get rid of the `Form1 form1 = new Form1();` in your classx.  That is making a *new* form1 that is different than the one you have presumably on the screen at the moment.  Change your function to `Times(string value)` and fix the errors from there.  Follow the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is this line:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

You create a new instance of the form and do nothing with it. This is not the same instance and the form that is already running. You are basically working with 2 different forms all together.

Change the code like this:

```
 public TimeSpan Times(string place)
    {
        double length = 0; double hour = 0, minute = 0, seconds = 0; int hour1 = 0, minute1 = 0, second1 = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            //this is the row which doesn't work
            if (Places[i] == place)
            {
                length = Kilometers[i];
            }
        }
        hour = (length / 80);
        hour1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(hour));
        minute = (hour - Math.Truncate(hour)) * 60;
        minute1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(minute));
        second = (minute - Math.Truncate(minute)) * 60;
        second1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(second));
        TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(hour), Convert.ToInt32(minute1), Convert.ToInt32(second1));
        TimeSpan TimeLength = new TimeSpan(hour1, minute1, second1);
        return TimeLength;
    }
```

and then in your form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        classx duration = new classx();
        var result = duration.Times(comboBox1.Text);

        MessageBox.Show("From " + comboBox1.Text + " to " + comboBox2.Text + " it takes around " + result);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, as it worked almost perfectly!
I changed  var result = duration.Times(comboBox2.Text); and values started to appear...except for Istabul. It shows me 0:00:00. The other cities are showing results (thanks a lot!), but to know if the program is right (according to the screenshot I got from), is to click on instanbul and show the result "01:07:30", but Istanbul is the only city which still showns "0:00:00". Could you look on that so that there is a result for Instanbul too? I would be really thankful!
Edit: I tried to increase the loop limit to 6, but the program broke down)

Comment: The only reason I can think is that they are not spelled the same in the array and the combobox?

Comment: ...I feel so embarrased from that. Thanks so much for your time. I really thank you from the depth of my heart! I hope I will learn new things from you :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you, that is what this site is for.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a problem with reading the text from the comboBox2 from Form1
>   to classx.

From your code lines in `classx`:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

`form1` is part of your item in the `classx` method. Then as long as the `comboBox2` [access modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) is `public` in the `Form1` then you should be easily access it like what you did:

```
form1.comboBox2 //this can be easily done
```

But the biggest problem here is since you declare new form in the `classx` and your form constructor looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        classx duration = new classx();

        MessageBox.Show("From " + comboBox1.Text + " to " + comboBox2.Text + " it takes around " + duration.Times());
    }
}
```

See that there is no value selected for `comboBox2` in the form initialization. That means your `comboBox2` will always select nothing. Thus you get nothing too in the `classx`

```
//this is the row which doesn't work
//it is because nothing is ever selected in the first place
if (form1.comboBox2.SelectedText.ToString() == Places[i])
{
    length = Kilometers[i];
}
```

You may want to put up selected index in the `Form1` constructor if needed be:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0; //assuming there is at least 1 item in the comboBox
}
```

But the best is **not** to call your **new** form in your `classx`. It is likely a waste.

Thus, I suggest you to do it **the other way round**: instead of having `form1` called from a method in `classx`, you should rather have `form1`, and then in `form1` you have your `classx` instance (say named `classx classxInstance`). And in the `classx` method `Times()` currently you receive no input. Change it to receive `string` input, you will need it to receive input from the `comboBox.SelectedText` -> declare it as this `Times(string input)` then you call it like this `classxInstance.Times(comboBox2.SelectedText)` from your `Form1` and things will be a lot better

Edit:

The other way round would look like this,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        classx duration = new classx();

        //Note that you should not use Text here, but selectedText
        //Note that now your classx takes input from comboBox2.SelectedText    
        MessageBox.Show("From " + comboBox1.SelectedText + " to " + comboBox2.SelectedText + " it takes around " + duration.Times(comboBox2.SelectedText));
    }
}
```

And your classx would look like

```
public class classx
{        
    public string[] Places = new string[] { "Berlin", "Paris", "London", "Rome", "Tirana", "Istanbul" };
    public int[] Kilometers = new int[] { 50, 30, 70, 110, 40, 90 };
    public TimeSpan Times(string input) //note the input string here
    {
        double length = 0; double hour = 0, minute = 0, seconds = 0; int hour1 = 0, minute1 = 0, second1 = 0;
        //Form1 form1 = new Form1(); //you don't need this

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            //this is the row which doesn't work
            if (input == Places[i]) //now you use input here
            {
                length = Kilometers[i];
            }
        }
        hour = (length / 80);
        hour1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(hour));
        minute = (hour - Math.Truncate(hour)) * 60;
        minute1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(minute));
        second = (minute - Math.Truncate(minute)) * 60;
        second1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(second));
        TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(hour), Convert.ToInt32(minute1), Convert.ToInt32(second1));
        TimeSpan TimeLength = new TimeSpan(hour1, minute1, second1);
        return TimeLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I did set the modifiers to public. I tried the suggested edit  "comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;" but the result was still 0:00:00, but I think you are right about calling a **new** form would reset the values. But how to I retreive the text from the form without Form1 form1=new Form1()?

Comment: I suggest you to do it the other way round: you have `form1`, and then in `form1` you have your `classx`. And in the classx method `Times()` currently you receive no input. Change it to receive `string` input from the `comboBox.SelectedText` -> declare it as this `Times(string input)` then you call it like this `Times(comboBox2.SelectedText)` from your `Form1` and things will be a lot better

Comment: I am sorry for not understaning , but could you paste the edited code?  I would be really thankful!

Comment: @FlorianI. ok, I updated my answer with the example code

Answer (score 0):

`ComboBox.SelectedText` already returns a string so theres no need to use the `.ToString()` method.

Comment: I tried form1.comboBox.SelectedText either, but it didn't work. I shows me 0:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues.

1) SelectedText will always be "" for a combo box unless you set it to something else, so you need to use SelectedItem instead.

2) You created a new form when you already likely have one created in the Program class.

Below is a fully functional example.

```
using System; using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testforms {
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    } }
```

Rather than create the form, have the form create classx such as.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testforms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private classx duration = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            duration = new classx(this);
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("From " + comboBox1.Text + " to " + comboBox2.Text + " it takes around " + duration.Times());
        }
    }

    public class classx 
    {
        public string[] Places = new string[] { "Berlin", "Paris", "London", "Rome", "Tirana", "Istanbul" };
        public int[] Kilometers = new int[] { 50, 30, 70, 110, 40, 90 };

        Form1 form1 = null;

        public classx(Form1 form)
        {
            form1 = form;

            form1.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Places);
            form1.comboBox2.Items.AddRange(Places);
        }

        public TimeSpan Times()
        {
            double length = 0; double hour = 0, minute = 0, seconds = 0; int hour1 = 0, minute1 = 0, second1 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                // change to SelectedItem because selected text will always be "" empty string.
                if (form1.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == Places[i])
                {
                    length = Kilometers[i];
                }
            }
            hour = (length / 80);
            hour1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(hour));
            minute = (hour - Math.Truncate(hour)) * 60;
            minute1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(minute));
            seconds = (minute - Math.Truncate(minute)) * 60;
            second1 = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(seconds));
            TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(hour), Convert.ToInt32(minute1), Convert.ToInt32(second1));
            TimeSpan TimeLength = new TimeSpan(hour1, minute1, second1);
            return TimeLength;
        }
    }
}
```

In the designer set your comboboxes to internal so they can be initialized from classx.

```
namespace testforms
{
    public partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.comboBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // comboBox1
            // 
            this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(36, 30);
            this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
            this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
            this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // comboBox2
            // 
            this.comboBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.comboBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(36, 91);
            this.comboBox2.Name = "comboBox2";
            this.comboBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
            this.comboBox2.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(36, 162);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click_1);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        internal System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
        internal System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
var result = duration.Times(Combo2.Text);
```

for all cities I have results but only for London I have 00:00:00

Comment: The only reason could be if the text in the comboBox2 isn't "London" but something else like "london" or "lndon". Look at the vector too for typos

Answer (score -1):

Check this:

```
string comboText = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Just to show that this works:

class:

```
public class classzz
{
    public string[] Places;
    public int[] Kilometers;

    public classzz() { 
        Places = new string[] { "Berlin", "Paris", "London" };
        Kilometers = new int[] { 50, 30, 70 };
    }

    public String ShowValues(string text1, int value) {
        return "The values selected were" + text1 + "-" + value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    protected classzz myClass;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myClass = new classzz();
        comboBox1.DataSource = myClass.Places;
        comboBox2.DataSource = myClass.Kilometers;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       label1.Text = myClass.ShowValues(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), Int32.Parse(comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to add it like this:    

comboText = form1.comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                if (comboText == Places[i])
                {
                    length= Kilometers[i];
                }
            }
Because it broke my program down, with an error saying :NullreferenceException was unhandled

Comment: Check LarsTech's comment on your original post: SelectedItem is the one you want.

Comment: I think that you should use `SelectedValue` and the `SelectedItem` is pretty the same because you can get the value from the Item itself to get the places

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera I know, right?! And none really work for me, neither SelectedItem nor SelectedValue :[

Comment: @FlorianI. Wait me a second I will give a test code that works

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it :)
P.S. I just created 2 comboboxes and a button in the form design, and I didn't rename them so the code should work for you once the mentioned items are created.